# I am trying to add forwarding rule to the user's mailbox but it is not working asexpected

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using graph API to add message rule which is forward a mail from user's inbox. Rule is getting added but mails are not forwarding to specified id.

Here are some details:

```
var data = {      
    "displayName": "From partner",      
    "sequence": 1,      
    "isEnabled": true,          
    "conditions": {
        "isAutomaticForward": true
     },
     "actions": {
        "forwardTo": [
          {
             "emailAddress": {
                "name": "recipient name ",
                "address": "email address"
              }
           }
        ],
        "stopProcessingRules": true
     }    
}
axios.post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules", data, 
{
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }
}
)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response)
})
```

Response is as expected but mails are not forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above payload, steps and it works for me!!

(1) Create a new rule using Graph API

```html
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules
 Content-type: application/json
    
 {      
     "displayName": "From partner",      
     "sequence": 2,      
     "isAutomaticForward": true,          
      "actions": {
         "forwardTo": [
           {
              "emailAddress": {
                 "name": "Alex Wilbur",
                 "address": "AlexW@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
               }
            }
         ],
         "stopProcessingRules": true
      }    
 }
```

(2) Test whether the rule is working or not.

Result: It's working as expected

(3) Check that the above rule shows or not (as part of Outlook.office.com or Outlook UI's rule section)

Adding a snapshot that i captured from Outlook.office.com, mailbox settings!!

[image]

Comment: It is working for admin (logged in user) but I want to add this for other users.

Comment: Then make sure you make application permission and set "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite" which will work for other users.

Comment: Yes, I am using client_credentials grant_type and I have also added MailboxSettings.ReadWrite.